# При передаче encoding как переменную в open возникает ошибка TypeError: 'str' object cannot be interpreted as an integer

Tags: python, кодировка, type-error

Как можно передать encoding в виде переменной в параметры open?
Этот код выполняется корректно:

```
open(file, 'r', encoding='utf_8_sig')
```

Здесь возникает ошибка TypeError: 'str' object cannot be interpreted as an integer

```
enс = 'utf_8_sig'
open(file, 'r', enс)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

А указать атрибут encoding?

Вот как надо делать:

```
enс = 'utf_8_sig'
open(file, 'r', encoding=enс)
```

Answer (score 2):

На третьем месте в [open()](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/functions.html#open) стоит параметр `buffering`, который должен быть числом. Поэтому надо или указать `encoding=enc`, или добавить аргумент для `buffering`:

```
open(file, 'r', -1, enс)
```